# How to check every 3rd element in a list and count the vowels in that string?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, count

a.  Define a list of strings called wordlist. The list should contain at least 10 strings.

b.  Starting with the first element (i.e. element 0) check every 3rd element of the list in a loop, (i.e. 0th element, 3th element, 6th element, 9th element  … and so on) and count the number of vowels in that string.

c.  Print the string and the number of vowels in the strung with a suitable message.

d.  If the string contains 3 or more vowels, exit the loop (don’t need to check remaining elements).

e.  If you exited the loop  after finding a string with 3 or more vowels, print ‘***Found string with 3 or more vowels!***’; otherwise print “***Did not find suitable string.***”

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

[image: EXAMPLE OUTPUT]

I am having trouble with part B if someone can guide me in the proper direction that would help

```
wordlist = ['hat' ,'bat' ,'cat','dog','bird','bear','lion','tiger','frog','mouse']
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: So we do your homework for you and you go get 100% without even attempting it yourself? But how will you pass the exam?

Comment: Try `print(['Did not find suitable string.','Found string with 3 or more vowels!'][any([_ for _ in[([_ for _ in __ if _ in"aeiou"],print("{} has {} vowel(s).".format(__,len([_ for _ in __ if _ in"aeiou"]))))for __ in wordlist[::3]]if len(_[False])>=3])])` ... or you may want to [edit] your question after reviewing [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
every_third_string = (string for i, string in enumerate(wordlist) if i % 3 == 0)
vowels = {'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 0 'u': 0}
for string in every_third_string:
    for char in string.lower():
        if char in vowels:
            vowels[char] += 1
```

This sounds like your homework. Make sure to go through this carefully, line-by-line, and understand why it works.

For example, what happens if we omit `if char in vowels`?
What does `i % 3 == 0` mean? What do we get if we try `i % 3 == 1` instead?

Why is it important to use `string.lower()`?

Comment: I doubt the OP will even have time to read this. He didn't even take the liberty of re framing his question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
wordlist = ['hat', 'bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'frog', 'mouse']

if len(wordlist) < 10:
    print("Error. list length must be grater than 10")
    exit(-1)
found = False
for word in wordlist[::3]:
    count = sum(map(word.lower().count, "aeiou"))
    if count >= 3:
        print('Found string with 3 or more vowels!')
        found = True
        break
    print("The string %s contains %d vowel(s)" % (word, count))
if not found:
    print("Did not find suitable string.")
```

Comment: `for i in range(0, len(wordlist), 3): word = wordlist[i]` can be replaced with `for word in wordlist[::3]:` using [extended slices](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

Answer (score 0):

First off, this looks a lot like a homework problem or something. That said, this isn't the place to ask for homework help and instead you should ask questions about general algorithms or strategies. Maybe it's not, so here's a general suggestion.

I don't think it has a specific example, but [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) may  help. For getting every nth index of a list (starting at 0) you can do list[0::n]. This returns a new list containing every nth entry of the original.

From there counting every vowel is pretty basic string manipulation and/or list comparison. Please show us what you've tried and we can give more specific feed back, but that's probably what you should be using.